# Tomcat fails to see users

Tags: linux, apache, tomcat, java-7

I'm trying to set up a tomcat 8 server. Everything has gone well except for the defining of the users. Everytime i try to login with given user account it refuses to login and asks me for my username and password again. I'm fairly new at this so i couldn't figure out what i did wrong.

Here's my the bit defining the users database:

```
<GlobalNamingResources>
<!-- Editable user database that can also be used by
     UserDatabaseRealm to authenticate users
-->
<Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
          type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
          description="User database that can be updated and saved"
          factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
          pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
```

And here is my tomcat-users.xml file:

```
<tomcat-users>
   <role rolename="manager-gui" />
   <role rolename="admin-gui" />
   <user username="admin" password="password" roles="admin-gui,manager-gui" />
   <user username="user" password="password" roles="manager-gui" />
</tomcat-users>
```

I'm connecting from a machine within the server's network.
Am i missing something?

Comment: It doesnt see the user accounts

Comment: so you're doing *something* which doesn't work, and you give us some configuration that you do to the environment your code doesn't work in. Can you specify that *something* a bit better (e.g. give code) so that it can be reproduced? Just defining a user database doesn't make anybody use it. Is it your custom code that should use it?

Comment: This is the way users should be defined according to the official Tomcat documentation... The thing that doesn't work is logging in to the administration panel, as described in my question. The default web page should take the users that are defined in between <tomcat-users> and </tomcat-users>, but still i cannot login.Asuming the official documentation is right... it should use this database...